# syntax error $global-radius in Zurb Foundation _settings.scss

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm getting this syntax-error.

I enabled the button-radius in settings.scss in foundation and got returned with this error.

Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$global-radius".
        on line 348 of scss/_settings.scss
        from line 1 of scss/app.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.

checked both of the files and can't seem to see the problem.

```
// We use this to set the default radius used throughout the core.
$button-radius: $global-radius;
// $button-round: $global-rounded;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`$global-radius` is either not defined, or is commented out. Try adding:

```
$global-radius = 3px;
```

at the top of your `_settings.scss` file and see if that fixes the problem. Or do a search for the `$global-radius` variable to make sure it's not commented out.

Comment: Added $global-radius = 3px; and still getting same message.

Searched in _global.scss and found this:
$global-radius: 3px !default;
$global-rounded: 1000px !default;
it is not commented out.

Comment: Still having the issue,

however when I create a custom class with the value <code>.first-button {
 @include button($bg: #FBB731, $radius: 5px);</code>
it is working.

Comment: Are you putting it at the top if the `_settings.scss` file so its defined before you use it?

Comment: Thanks Brett. Yes I did, it worked when I put it with : instead of =